# __autoload() help and understanding

Tags: php

I'm trying to use the __autoload() magic method but I don't really understand it

I'm using it like this

```
function __autoload($class)
{
     require_once("./path/to/classes/".$class.".php");
}
```

Ok, a few questions about this. I have 5 class files in my 'classes/' folder and I have a naming structure like so: `access.class.php`

One thing I notice is that I cannot load more than 4 classes for some reason, I get an error from my php error reporting that the Class: ClassNameHere is not found or something.

so I tweaked the require_once to

```
require_once(strtolower("./path/to/classes/".$class.".class.php"));
```

great that works but now I'm back to me wondering why I cannot load more than 4 classes??

I have one main class and 3 others that extend that class.

Comment: Put here your FS structure (with classes that your require), and __autoload function (real function), and error from log (not like this ClassNameHere)

Comment: I wouldnt bother with individual `__autoload` but just use `spl_autoload_register`

Comment: There is no limit on autoloaded classes. What are the names of your classes and filenames? Using strtolower might bring problems if filesystem paths are case-sensitive.

Comment: I have a class called access.class.php and authenticate.class.php for instance but when i do a print_r($class) it prints out Access and Authenticate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function __autoload($class)
{
     require_once("./path/to/classes/".$class.".php");
}
```

your funciton is looking for  className.php  but your files are className.class.php so you must use as:

```
function __autoload($class)
{
     require_once("./path/to/classes/".$class.".class.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the __autoload() working, you don't need the require_once before the call of the class! It will be autoloaded.

Comment: How can that be? He'd obviously have to require the class in there.

Comment: and here it is? Author don`t says that he use require directly

Answer (score -1):

> You may define an __autoload function which is automatically called in case you are trying to use a class/interface which hasn't been defined yet. By calling this function the scripting engine is given a last chance to load the class before PHP fails with an error.

So, actually, when you try instantiating a class which is not loaded yet, the __autoload function is called and the name of the class passed as a param. I suggest you try configuring an array with all the class paths you have in your app. So if you have say class User which is situated in ./_classes/Users.php your config array would look like $CFG['classes']['User']="./_classes/Users.php"; The autoload function will then look like:

```
function __autoload($className){
    global $CFG;
    include_once($CFG['classes'][$className]);
}
```

More lecturing on: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: @azat: you don't say? any arguments to why it is a bad ideea? :)

Comment: I'll only consider this option when I only have a handful of class files, say 5, and they are saved on diff parts of the filesystem.

Comment: Class names must be like that, `FooBarSimple.php`, and location is `Foo/Bar/Simple.php`, or as PHP 5.3, the same with namespaces, and if classes more than hundred use array of classes is not a good idea, do not you think so?

Comment: yeah but what if u have classes like adodb or smarty which obviously have to be held in different dirs on the disk?

Comment: What I do is to generate several file paths, and do `require` if `file_exists` returns true. The pattern is the key. You can also use spl_autoload_register to register multiple autoload functions.